# Getting ping error with aptana plugin for STS

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, aptana

I am getting a weird ping error with the aptana studio plugin and eclipse?  Has anyone else hit this issue?

the error is:
An internal error occurred during: "Sending Ping...".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Harry, I edited the question with some more details about the error.

Comment: The question is still a little vague.  Do you have a stack trace in the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown and deactivate “Aptana Studio Core User Interface”

More notes here: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/472-aptana-studio-20-sending-ping-error-on-startup/page/1